# SSRS BIDS 2008 Bubble chart - Bubble placement

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, bubble-chart

Is it possible to decide where the bubbles on a bubble diagram are placed, the placement seems random and some bubbles have overlapping when there is plenty of space elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only was to have control over the placement is to use appropriate x and y axis based on where you want the bubble to be placed.

Answer (score 0):

Chart properties, look at interval and scale.

Comment: Can anyone give me a step by step guide as to how to do this?